# Check for case insensitive in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a blacklist but I need it to be case insensitive since there would be any combination of lowercase and uppercase. How can I do this in this script below, so that it catches "perv, Perv, PERV, nAsty, badword, WoRd" etc?

```
$words_arr = ['word', 'nasty', 'perv'];
$included = [];

foreach($words_arr as $word)
if (stripos($message, $word) !== false) {
    $included []= $word;
}
```

My guess is to turn `$message` into lowercase and then match, and then check to see if the words in the array exist by themselves or as part of any word.

Comment: _str-contains_ is case sensitive: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **strtolower()** function for convert your string to lower characters.

```
    if (stripos(strtolower($message), $word) !== false) {
    $included []= $word;
}
```

Since the array you created will already contain lowercase banned words, it will match.